# Type checking in Angular 2 templates

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

We are building an application in Angular 2 and TypeScript. We try to statically check types where it is possible. Is there any way to check types in templates? Consider the following fragment:

```
<foo [data]="dataObj"></foo>
```

Assume that `data` in `Foo` component has some type `TData`. However, by default, nothing prevents me from passing `dataObj` that does not conform to `TData`. Is there a typescript extension for Angular templates that would verify the types in such a case?

Comment: Currently there isn't any "plugin" that does that (You will need typescript for that).
Angular2 did put a lot of effort in making their code, and templates accessable for IDEs, but that's the future.

Comment: @gilamran  How do I do it even with TypeScript?

Comment: After thinking about it for a bit, maybe a solution would be a wrapper function? something like `<foo [data]="typeCheck(expectedtype,dataObj)> </foo>"` where the expectedtype should match the type of `[data]`. Granted, it would require a little more effort on the programmers part, but it's the only way I could think of right now. I'm gonna get around to trying this soon, and if it works, I'll post an answer.

Comment: Can't you use typeof inside Angular 2 template expressions? Just a thought

Comment: I know this isn't a true "solution" but when you use AOT compilation your templates get compiled into the resulting files, then when those ngfactory TS files get transpiled any typescript errors will be found. This differs from JIT compilation since with JIT the template compilation happens runtime and so there is no Typescript checking involved. When I first tried to run my project with AOT I found all sorts of previously unreported Type errors and private variables/ methods being accessed from templates.

Comment: @dmungin: I think AOT is a "true solution", the question was asked before  AOT was available.

Comment: @dmungin, could you put a bit more detail into the AOT approach? When I access {{ foo.bar }} in a template where foo is not a member of my corresponding component and I compile using "ng build --aot", nothing happens, all green. I was very disappointed to find out that VSCode would not give me auto completion in templates. Is there any update on that situation? Looking at all the stuff the IDE is capable of, I really think like this couldn't be that much of a problem...

Comment: Typechecking should not be a side-effect of your build process. AOT should not even generate TypeScript. If it didn't it would behave the same way as JIT mode. Both modes should have the same typechecking behavior and they do not. Bad

Comment: @Aluan Haddad: static type checking is by its nature a "side effect" of build / compilation process. This is exactly what we want - to check the types before running the application.

Comment: @jfu that's not correct. For example `tsc --noEmit`

Answer (score 16):

Since Angular 9 the solution is `strictTemplates` flag of Angular compile options, see [Strict mode](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#strict-mode) section of [Template type checking](https://angular.io/guide/template-typecheck#template-type-checking) guide. Enable the flag in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    ...
    "compilerOptions": { ... },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "strictTemplates": true
        ...
    }
}
```

---

**Original answer:**

Unfortunately, It seems that current Angular version doesn't check types of component inputs and events. You can use [AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) compilation and enable [fullTemplateTypeCheck](https://next.angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#fulltemplatetypecheck) angular compiler option, which performs some template type checking.

Enable fullTemplateTypeCheck option in `src/tsconfig.app.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": { ... },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true
        ...
    }
}
```

And build (or serve) your project with `--aot` option

```
ng build --aot
```

What about inputs and events type checking, I found two issues on angular bug tracker ([issue1](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20600) and [issue2](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16952)). As I understand, the solution of the problem depends on renderer implementation, and more likely that the problem may be fixed in next version of angular renderer, called [Ivy](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21706). [Here is](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24625) feature request for inputs type checking in ivy renderer.

Comment: But this still doesn't check component inputs, correct? I tried sending in wrong inputs and got no error with `ng build --aot`

Comment: @UrbKr, Yes, It seems that AOT compilation doesn't force inputs type checking. You can find more detailed information in my updated answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not check the types of objects extracted from async pipes either

Comment: i used {"fullTemplateTypeCheck": true} in my tsconfig.json  but after all its neither working nor compile html template.

Answer (score 0):

[WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) from Jetbrains can do that.

My original answer:

> I don't think there's a reliable way to do that without doing some
>   think like React does with the JSX or TSX extension to the language.
>
> The typescript compiler doesn't know about your HTML files, and will
>   just ignore them. Also, there's no strong coupling between your
>   templates and the Controller code... there's nothing preventing you
>   from reusing the same template across several controllers.

Comment: There is AOT now, which takes the templates into account.

Comment: Also, just noticed that WebStorm, from Jetbrains, is able to check variable types on templates.

Answer (score 0):

to quote the official statement:

> In the template type-checking phase, the Angular template compiler uses the TypeScript compiler to validate the binding expressions in templates.
>
> Template validation produces error messages when a type error is detected in a template binding expression, similar to how type errors are reported by the TypeScript compiler against code in a .ts file.

More at:

Angular Template checking https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#binding-expression-validation

Yet to activate it, you should build the app, by

```
ng build --aot
```

or

`ng build --prod`

but you can also activate it without building:

`ng serve --aot`

Answer (score -1):

I think an IDE or linter might catch this for you, but if someone really needs this, one option would be to create a Pipe to do the type checking at run time.

```
@Pipe({ name: 'typeCheck' })
export class TypeCheckPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, classType: object): any[] {
    if (value &&
      !(value instanceof classType)
    ) {
        throw new TypeError("Input is not instanceof " + classType + 
                            " but was " + typeof(value));
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

You can use it in a component template like this:

```
<custom-component [coolInput]="coolInput | typeCheck:coolInputClass"></custom-component>
```

The only catch I found is that I'm not sure how to inject the class function into the template other than as an instance of the component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <custom-component [coolInput]="coolInput | typeCheck:coolInputClass"></custom-component>
  </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  coolInput: CoolInput;
  coolInputClass: object = CoolInput;

  constructor() {
    this.coolInput = "This is the wrong type";
  }
}
```

Here is a Plunker illustrating the working error message (thrown via Zone).
https://plnkr.co/edit/WhoKSdoKUFvNbU3zWJy6?p=preview

Comment: The question is about checking this statically and not at runtime

Comment: Oh I see. Thought it was an odd request. I believe you cannot do that with typescript itself. You need an extra tool to check the template files, since they are not processed by typescript. Like a linter perhaps. However, I don't know of a tool currently that validates types of angular2 component inputs.

Comment: Linter wont catch this for you.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using visual studio code, you could try out the [language service](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Angular.ng-template) extension. Its still under heavy development, and you could consider it in beta. But when I would definitely say that it have made me more productive. Not only its type checking, but also cmd + clicking components to go to their source.

If I am not mistaken, [this](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service) project will eventually be merged to vscode it self when its somewhat stable as its in vscode's best interest to keep angular developers productive.

You can rest assured about the extension's support because it's being worked on by the angular team. For more information checkout this [readme](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2150b45954cd2776c0adc52951c7b450a2eb66b8/aio/content/guide/language-service.md)

**Edit:** sublime text and webstorm support this too.

Answer (score -1):

Your components Input() should have the type. Let's say you have a list component

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Items } from '../../../services/Items';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-list',
  templateUrl: './my-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-list.component.scss'],
})
export class CategoryListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() items: Items;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

"Items" should be defined as a interface and imported

```
export interface List {
  name: string,
  children: Items[]
}

export interface Item {
  name: string;
  slug: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  children: Item[];
}
```

now you can use it like this

```
<my-list [items]="items"></my-list>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a Pipe:

```
export class ObjectTypePipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): string {
        if (value != undefined && value != null) {
            return value.constructor.name.toString();
        }
        return "";
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to do a string comparison.