# Wrapping Types to ensure run time type checking in Angular 2 templates

Tags: angularjs, typescript

A big problem, which has cost me hours already is, that inside of Angular 2 templates there is no type checking. This was already discussed in [Type checking in Angular 2 templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33668739/type-checking-in-angular-2-templates). (But the only solution provided was AOT compilation)

**The problem:**

```
@Component({
    template: '<button (click)="foo='haha'"'><div>{{foo}}</div>'
})
export class Bar {
    foo: number = 3;
}
```

This will set foo to "haha", which is not a huge problem, since we see the output, but in bigger apps this becomes more complicated and often is not as obvious. (E.g. looping over a dictionary with *ngFor and putting in the wrong type as a key).

**Possible solution:**
My idea is, to wrap the types i am working with, and on top of typescripts checking, ensure the types match at run time:

```
function checkTypes(shouldBe: any, value: any) {
    if(typeof shouldBe !== typeof value)
        throw "Typemissmatch. Expected a " + typeof shouldBe + ", but the provided variable '" + value + "' is of type " + typeof value + ".";
}

abstract class Typesafe<T> {
    private _value: T;

    constructor(start: T) {
        this._value = start;
    }

    get value(): T {
        return this._value;
    }

    set value(value: T) {
        checkTypes(this._value, value)
        this._value = value;
    }
}

export class TInt extends Typesafe<number> {};
```

This actually works perfectly. If i now click the button in the example, an exception is thrown.

**The questions:**

- What downsides (apart from writing a lot more types) does this approach have
- Am i am missing out on some super awesome technologies, which solve this problem? (e.g. JSX compilation for React)
- Has anyone already implemented this?